# How do I put 1 variable in an array()?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I need to put a variable within an array.

For example.

```
$anarray = array("1","3","4");
foreach($anarray as $value){ // do such and such
```

I need the array() to include a variable instead. To be exact, I need it to contain a variable from my table in my database.

In effect, I would want my array to look like this.

Column 'example' in my users table contains - `"1","3","4"`

When I rewrite the code to look like this ...

```
$anarray = array($users['example']);
foreach($anarray as $value){ // do such and such
```

It doesn't work. What do I need to do to that variable to make it read the exact same as if it were the actual characters?

Comment: Generally its not a good idea to store comma-separated values in a database like that. You should look into database normalization.

Comment: use implode to convert your array into string like `implod(",",$users['example'])`, you don't need foreach for that

Answer (score 0):

```
$anarray=array("1","2","3");
$new_array['example']=array();    
for($i=0;$i<count($anarray);$i++){
array_push($new_array['example'],$anarray[$i]);
}
```

Comment: explain your answer

Comment: It was fixed. By using $someArray = str_split($users['example']); it worked perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, it actually didn't work. It was ok until the numbers passed 10.

Comment: I want numbers that are input into my table to be used as an array later. How can this be done?

Comment: are you saying you want to save your table inputs in a 2D array?